# Delete query not working sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I am creating a app in which i have used sqlite db.I have successfully created the table and inserted data into it.But when i try to delete the data , the query doesn't seems to be working.

Code

```
public void deleteSubject(int Id) {
        String query = "DELETE  FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DataBaseColumns.SUBJECT_ID + "=" + Id;
//        String whereClause = DataBaseColumns.SUBJECT_ID + "=?";
        database = openDb();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
//            result = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, new String[Id]);
            cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("Error in delete Subjects", e.getMessage());
        }
        database = closeDb();
        cursor.close();


    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for `DELETE` queries.

`rawQuery()` only compiles the SQL but does not run it until the cursor is moved.  `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Comment: Sit thankz it worked.But sir i have one more prob that the list is not being notified when delete occurs

Comment: You're not modifying the array your adapter is working on. It still has the old data.

Comment: Please don't modify the problem in question. If you need extensive help with something else, ask a new question.